# Why is bulk modulus positive in equilibrium?

Tags: pressure, definition, equilibrium, elasticity, volume

$B=-PV/\Delta V$ The negative sign indicates that when pressure increases, the volume
decreases. That is, if $P$ is positive, $\Delta V$ is negative. Thus for a system in
equilibrium, the value of bulk modulus $B$ is always positive.
If the negative sign already indicates that the volume decreases when pressure increases then why do we have to substitute $\Delta V$ as -ve again in the case of equilibrium to make Bulk modulus positive?

Comment: I think your definition is incorrect: here we talk about a change of pressure in respect to change of volume: $B=-V\Delta P/\Delta V$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus). Perhaps this already answers the question...

Comment: The definition is from my textbook. Perhaps it is wrong.Can you tell me what happens when the system is in equilibrium

Comment: Your description is however consistent with the definition that I have - it is a change of pressure in respect to change of the volume. Both $P$ and $V$ are always positive, while their changes, $\Delta P$ and $Delta V$ can be either positive or negative.

Comment: @RogerVadim:  Maybe the textbook has defined $P$ as gauge pressure rather than absolute pressure?  That would be a non-standard way of doing things, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that could be.